# How to access "idpConfig" value in signinform.jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, cxf-fediz

How to access "idpConfig" value in signinform.jsp page like idplist.jsp

version: Apache CXF Fediz 1.4.2 (https://github.com/apache/cxf-fediz)

Please help me what changes required to get "idpConfig" value